# problem from inequalities chapter

Tags: inequality

prove that if $(1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_n)=2^n$, then $a_1a_2a_3...a_n\le1$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: The imperative is general convention in the writing of math problems. I think it's fine as it is.

Comment: @MihirSinghal: The imperative is fine for the problem itself; demanding that users prove that given result (without any other context or explanation) is not.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Try using the fact that $1+a_i \ge 2\sqrt{a_i}$